# copying function pointer throws error in one function pointer

Tags: casting, malloc, function-pointers

I have cjson code (https://github.com/kbranigan/cJSON/blob/master/ ) , it compiles well when I compile on the linux pc .

but when I compile for some embedded platform it throws error at

```
if (!hooks) { /* Reset hooks */
    cJSON_malloc = mem_alloc; // its equal to gcc malloc for the embedded compiler
    cJSON_free = mem_free; // its equal to gcc free
}
```

The error is Undefined reference to mem_alloc , and mem_free 
but  if I call the function like  below 
     char* data = (char*) mem_alloc(32);
     it compiles well .. 
compiler is xtensa compiler(xt-xcc) 
isn't it right way to assign ?